# Animating a UIButton prevents it from causing a segue

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uiviewanimation, touch-event

In my storyboard, I have a button that triggers a modal segue. When it doesn't trigger any animations that move it, it works as intended. However, when it *does* trigger an animation that moves it, it does not trigger the segue.

Additional Information:

- The animation is triggered when a user taps on `view`, the direct superview of the button
- The animation is done in conjunction with a keyboard event, so that `view` "follows" the keyboard. The segue is created through the storyboard
- I also tried it using the `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` method, and it still didn't work.

Code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect newFrame = view.frame;
    //newFrame.origin.y += offset > keyboardFrame.size.height  ?  keyboardFrame.size.height  :  keyboardFrame.size.height - offset;
    UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
        view.frame = newFrame;
    }completion:nil];
}];
```